# Llenar Formulario PDF PHP y JS

Tags: php, javascript, html

Estoy haciendo una pagina web con html y js y php, pero uno de los requerimientos es que pueda llenar un formulario pdf [form pdf](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/fw9.pdf) he pensado hacer un formulario con los campos que se necesitan y luego poder generar el pdf encontre una librería de php [fpd](http://www.fpdf.org/) con la cual puedo armarme un pdf

```
<?php
require('fpdf.php');

class PDF extends FPDF
{
// Cabecera de página
function Header()
{
    // Logo
    $this->Image('logo.png',10,8,33);
    // Arial bold 15
    $this->SetFont('Arial','B',15);
    // Movernos a la derecha
    $this->Cell(80);
    // Título
    $this->Cell(30,10,'Title',1,0,'C');
    // Salto de línea
    $this->Ln(20);
}

// Pie de página
function Footer()
{
    // Posición: a 1,5 cm del final
    $this->SetY(-15);
    // Arial italic 8
    $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
    // Número de página
    $this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');
}
}

// Creación del objeto de la clase heredada
$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Times','',12);
for($i=1;$i<=40;$i++)
    $pdf->Cell(0,10,'Imprimiendo línea número '.$i,0,1);
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

pero revisando el pdf esta un poco complejo poder armar toda la estructura de ese pdf con esta librería.

Así que revisando en algunas paginas encontré que pueden cargar el archivo pdf y lo modifican en la misma pagina web [ejemplo](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/fw9.pdf) pero no encuentro ningún ejemplo de como hacerlo.

Agradecería si alguien que ha tenido que hacer algo similar pueda orientarme de la mejor manera de hacerlo

Comment: Sería más fácil si lo intentas con [domPdf](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf), que te permite generar un documento PDF a partir de código HTML.

Comment: Pero hacer el html del documento seria algo complicado(es un documento legal que debe quedar 10% igual) por eso buscaba la alternativa de poder editar el pdf directo